# How do i create a function that will change the property inside an object that is located inside of an array, in a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, function, object, namespaces

so ive been currently stuck on a JavaScript assignment for hours now.

so ive been given a Json file with the following data :

```
{
    "owner": "Jun31d",
    "info": [{ "id": 1, "name": "bob", "flavour": "vanilla", "age": 43 },
             { "id": 2, "name": "Juneid", "flavour": "Chocolate", "age": 19 },
             { "id": 3, "name": "Patrick", "flavour": "Strawberry", "age": 25 },
             { "id": 4, "name": "Jean", "flavour": "Mint", "age": 31 },
             { "id": 5, "name": "Ahmad", "flavour": "vanilla", "age": 18 },
             { "id": 6, "name": "Ali", "flavour": "Bubblegum", "age": 19 },
             { "id": 7, "name": "Frank", "flavour": "Pistachio", "age": 23 }
            ]
}
```

The instruction for my assigment is the following :

[Instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azk5I.png)

So from what ive understood i need to create a function that holds two string parameters, And ill need to change the property inside of my object that is located in an array to a new property.

And until now heres what i did :

```
'use strict'

const iceCream = require('./main.json')

let namespace = {

    changeProp : function (newprop,oldprop) {
        for (let oldprop in iceCream.info) {
           
        }
    }


}
```

I know it is not much at all, but i just want some help to know how can i move forward a little bit more on my assigment.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Please explain with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily replace the `oldKey` with `newKey` using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const data = {
  owner: "Jun31d",
  info: [
    { id: 1, name: "bob", flavour: "vanilla", age: 43 },
    { id: 2, name: "Juneid", flavour: "Chocolate", age: 19 },
    { id: 3, name: "Patrick", flavour: "Strawberry", age: 25 },
    { id: 4, name: "Jean", flavour: "Mint", age: 31 },
    { id: 5, name: "Ahmad", flavour: "vanilla", age: 18 },
    { id: 6, name: "Ali", flavour: "Bubblegum", age: 19 },
    { id: 7, name: "Frank", flavour: "Pistachio", age: 23 },
  ],
};

function changePropertyName(arr, oldName, newName) {
  return arr.map((o) => {
    return Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      curr === oldName ? (acc[newName] = o[oldName]) : (acc[curr] = o[curr]);
      return acc;
    }, {});
  });
}

console.log(changePropertyName(data.info, "flavour", "bestFlavour"));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it. Easy, simple and nasty solution.

```js
const data = {
  owner: 'Jun31d',
  info: [
    { id: 1, name: 'bob', flavour: 'vanilla', age: 43 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Juneid', flavour: 'Chocolate', age: 19 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Patrick', flavour: 'Strawberry', age: 25 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Jean', flavour: 'Mint', age: 31 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Ahmad', flavour: 'vanilla', age: 18 },
    { id: 6, name: 'Ali', flavour: 'Bubblegum', age: 19 },
    { id: 7, name: 'Frank', flavour: 'Pistachio', age: 23 }
  ]
};

const renameProperty = (a, e, n) =>
    a.map((el) => {
        el[n] = el[e];
        delete el[e];
        return el;
    });

console.log(renameProperty(data.info, "id", "_id"));
```